# Hide Rows when a cell is populated

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I have a list of data(tasks) in cells A2 to E2, and in column F is the option for my team to assign their name to it. What I'm trying to make happen, is as a name is inputted in F2, F3, F4.... the respective row disappears.

Example.

F1="Bob" , then row 1 dissapears.

This is what I have so far, but I have a feeling I might be going in the wrong direction with it.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Set r = Range("a1:a299")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In r
        If Len(c.text) = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm also not sure if this will update it straight away, or I'll have to run the macro everytime. If I've got it right, it should do the first.

Comment: you want to use the Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range) event not the activate event.  Then just check the target to see if it is the F column then check the value and hide the row if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'check to make sure we only have 1 cell
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        'check the column
        If Target.Column = 6 Then 'F column
            'check text length and if greater then 0 hide the row
            If Len(Target.Text) > 0 Then
                Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Target.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```